# Mist wallet doesn't synch

Tags: mist

Any ideas on what would cause my Mist wallet to become inordinately slow to synchronize?  When I opened Mist this evening and after the initial start up, I saw a message on the banner indicating "Incorrect date since last synch".  After about half an hour it finally synched at the contract I had started went through.  Then after initiating another contract, it denied the transfer and is now show a message:  "12 minutes since last block"

EDIT:  After reading several other related posts, discovered that the version of Mist I was running had issues with the high DAO traffic that was running.  Since I was 'watching' this contract, it was bogging down my machine and basically the wallet just stopped working.  I stopped 'watching' the contract by deleting it and now it runs fine.